# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - iOS device Ionic 3

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, ionic3, cordova-plugins

It shows this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

I have used this CLI and tested on iOS device ver `12.1.1`:

```
ionic cordova run ios --prod --device
```

**Note:** This is working fine on an Android device. Any clue?

*.html*

```
 <ion-slide *ngFor='let page of pages | normalizeUri'>
      <img [src]='page.documentPreviewImageFileUri' />
   </ion-slide>
```

*pipe.ts*

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'normalizeUri',
  pure: false
})
export class NormalizeUriPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private imageHandlingProvider: ImageHandlingProvider) { }
  transform(pages: Page[]): string[] {
    return pages.map((p) => {
      return this.imageHandlingProvider.normalizeImageFileUri(p.documentPreviewImageFileUri || p.originalPreviewImageFileUri);
    });
  }

}
```

*provider.ts*

```
import { normalizeURL } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class ImageHandlingProvider {

  constructor() {
  }

  normalizeImageFileUri(imageFileUri: string): string {
    console.log('imageFileUri', imageFileUri);
    console.log('imageFileUri-normalizeURL', normalizeURL(imageFileUri));
    return normalizeURL(imageFileUri);
  }
```

Some console out put:

```
 [Log] imageFileUri – "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C7C43E62-A782-4CA1-97A6-
    AE19B319EA16/Library/Application%20Support/net.doo.ScanbotSDK/SBSDK_I…" 
    (cordova.js, line 1732) 

    [Warning] normalizeURL is deprecated, use 
    window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc (cordova.js, line 1732) [Log] 

imageFileUri-normalizeURL – 
    "http://localhost:8080/_file_/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C7C43E62-
    A782-4CA1-97A6-AE19B319EA16/Library/Application%20Support/net.d…" (cordova.js, 
    line 1732)
```

Plugin:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="1.2.1" />
```

Comment: Which is your `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` version? from **2.0.0** `normalizeUrl` is [deprecated](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-2018-07-23)

Comment: Due to that I use this `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="1.2.1" />` @SurajRao

Comment: Then the deprecation log is weird